# error in calling a mysql stored procedure from a php page

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin

Using phpmyadmin, i created a mysql stored procedure called `mySP()`. After creating the SP, i noticed that the SP is located in the information_schema db under ROUTINE table. I can see it here. Now from within phpmyadmin, under my actual database if i use SQL tab and do a call to the procedure using:
CALL mySP();

it works as required. NO issues.

Now i am trying to extend this by having a php page call this SP.

my php code is like this:

```
<?php

include("include_db_connection.php");


    $callSP_query = "CALL mySP()";

    $callSP_result =    mysqli_query($db_conn, $callSP_query) 
                            or die('Connected to database, but StoredProc failed');

        if(!$callSP_result)                 
        {
            echo "Error with StoredProc...";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Succsess! Called Stored Proc..";
        }   

?>
```

Now on loading this page on the browser, i always get the 'Connected to database, but StoredProc failed' error meaning that connection to db was established successfully, but there is some problem with calling the SP.

what could be the problem? The SP was created successfully and even called successfully from within phpmyadmin. where is the php call going wrong?

thanks!

#### EDIT:

I just checked the error code using mysqli_error() and it says "PROCEDURE mySP does not exist"

Comment: Use `mysql_error()` to get an actual error message from mySQL

Comment: @Pekka - the error is "PROCEDURE mySP does not exist"  :) 
I had created mySP using phpmyadming, and like i said, a call to this SP from within phpmyadmin still works.

Comment: I get the issue. My database connection asks it to connect to my actual database.. but this proc is not in my actual db, but i guess in the information_schema. should i specify path to this?

Answer (score 0):

this was an issue with my own code. actually, u dont have to reference or even look into the information_schema. your sp can be called with the above code, if your database connection details are correct :)